# Synchronising AVAudioEngine audio recording with backing track, using AirPods

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avcapturesession, avaudioengine, airpods

I'm trying to identify how much latency is being experienced when using AirPods, compared to using the device mic & speaker, for the purposes of recording user video & audio that must be synchronised to a backing track.

Here's how my system currently works:

I have a recording pipeline that uses AVCaptureSession to record video, and AVAudioEngine to record audio.

During the recording process, I play audio via AVAudioEngine, which the user will 'perform to'. I create a movie file using AVAssetWriter where the user's captured audio (utilising noise cancellation) is added to the file, and the backing audio file is written into a separate track.

The audio file's presentation timestamps are modified slightly to account for the initial playback delay experienced in AVAudioEngine., and this works well (I previously used AVPlayer for audio playback and the start delay was more significant, and that's what led to making use of this technique).

I know about AVAudioSession's inputLatency, outputLatency and bufferDuration properties, and I've read that these can be used to identify latency, at least in one sense. I notice that this calculation yields a total round-trip latency of around 0.01s when using the device on its own, and 0.05 seconds when using AirPods' inputs and outputs.

This is useful, and I can apply that extra time difference in my own logic to improve synchronisation, but there is definitely additional latency in the output, and I can't identify its source.

Strangely, it looks as though the recorded audio and video are in sync, but not in sync with the backing track. This makes me think that the system is still adding compensation to one of those two forms of captured media, but it doesn't relate the active played-back audio, and so the user is potentially listening to delayed-playback audio and I'm not accounting for that extra delay.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what other considerations may be required? I feel as though most use cases for bluetooth synchronisation will be to either synchronise audio and visual output, or to synchronise only the audio and visual input when recording, not a third factor whereby the user is performing alongside an audio or video source on device that is later added to a resultant asset writing session/media file.